# About some notation of the derivative

Tags: calculus, notation

I'm currently Rudin's Principles of mathematical analysis, there is this definition of the "partial derivative". If $f$ maps an open set $E\subseteq R^n$ into $R^m$ and $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ and $\{u_1,...,u_m\}$ are the standard bases of $R^n$ into $R^m$ and the components of $f$ are defined as $f_i(x)=f(x)\cdot u_i$, $1\le i\le m$.

For $x\in E, 1\le i\le m, 1\le j\le m$ we define:

\begin{equation}
    D_j f_i(x)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f_i(x+te_j)-f_i(x)}{t}
\end{equation}

provided this limit exists.

That notation is rarely used but as I find it very consistent, it's clear that $D_j f_i$ is a function itself and that $D_j f_i(x)$ is the function at $x$. However most people usually use the $\frac{\partial f}{x_j}$ notation that makes very little sense to me no matter how you try to define it:

According to wikipedia:
\begin{equation}
\frac{ \partial }{\partial a_i }f(\mathbf{a}) =
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}{f(a_1, \dots , a_{i-1}, a_i+h, a_{i+1}, \dots ,a_n) -
f(a_1, \dots, a_i, \dots ,a_n) \over h }
\end{equation}

If that is understood to be an equality, one should be able to replace the $a's$ but that leads us to things like:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial }{\partial{2}}f(1,2)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1,2+t)-f(1,2)}{h}
\end{equation}

In this question [Formalizing Those Readings of Leibniz Notation that Don't Appeal to Infinitesimals/Differentials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23975/formalizing-those-readings-of-leibniz-notation-that-dont-appeal-to-infinitesima) , someone mentioned a notation like $f^{(0,0,1)}$ that is essentially the same as Rudin's but then said that a problem with this notation is that partial differentiation may not commute, how can this be a problem? one might just say that $f^{(0,0,1),(0,1,0)}$ is not always the same as $f^{(0,1,0),(0,0,1)}$ and write $f^{(0,1,1)}$ when they are indeed equal.

But the latter notation is hardly used, and the $\partial$ notation is preferred despite its ambiguity and nonsense (what is exactly the job of the "$-$" and the extra $\partial$ in the notation?).

So why do people keep using the $\partial$ notation, Is there some inconvenience to the $D_j f$ notation or the $f^{(0,0,1)}$ notation?

Comment: Pay attention: in wikipedia you find $\frac{ \partial }{\partial x_i }f$ not $\frac{ \partial }{\partial a_i }f$.

Comment: TonyPiccolo Look at the formal definition part.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't see: surely it is a typo.

Comment: The order of computing $\frac{\partial}{\partial a_i}f(a)$ should be first regarding $a_i$ as a variable, computing the derivative, and substitute the value of $a_i$ into the result. Not the reverse.

Answer (score 3):

There are some advantages to the $\partial f/\partial x_i$ notation:

1. It recalls the definition of the derivative a limit of a fraction
2. More importantly, it allows you to view the chain rule as 'cancelling out' parts of the derivative
3. In statistical mechanics, one often inverts the symbol to get the derivative of the inverse.
4. The parallels with the integral notation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main reason is that nobody has to take the time to define a function when you write things like
$$
    \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(x^{2}+2txy+y^{2}+r^{2})=2xy.
$$
I find order of variables to be far more artificial in such cases than standard partial derivatives.